# regular expression in python to extract words that contain @ but not dot

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python to extract words from a text. I want to extract word that contain@ but not dot.

Regular expression **should match** following: `@bob`, `cat@bob` 
Regular expression should **not** match: `xyz@bob.com`.

I tried following: `(?:\w+)?@\w+(?!\.)` - but it extracts `@bob`, `cat@bob` and `xyz@bo`.

Just  to elaborate, if I have text `"hi @bob and cat@bob my email is xyz@bob.com"` I want to extract `@bob` and `cat@bob` only from this text. My regular expression above extracts part of `xyz@bob.com` (precisely it extracts `xyz@bo`). How can I avoid extracting `xyz@bob.com` completely.

Comment: your test cases are not clear. please give 3 typical input and expected output.

Comment: Your regex works for me as expected(so, doesn't find pattern in the last string).....Are you sure you saved your code before running finally ^^

Comment: Regex is not required for this.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find a solution. The following expression worked for me: (?:\w+)?@\w+\b(?!.)

Comment: this works too: `[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]*\s`

Comment: `\w*@\w+\b(?!\.)` will do. No need to require one or more chars (with `\w+`) and then make them all optional (with an optional non-capturing group, `(?:...)?`). `(?:a+)?` = `a*`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. That about leading dot?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. I further modified the expression so that it matches xyz@bob. (i.e. when this comes at the end of sentence) but not xyz@bob.com -- `\w*@\w+\b(?!\.\w+)`